# Can't update state in component did mount hook react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Cannot update state inside component did mount hook, even tried using useLayoutEffect, still no solution

```
function App() {
  const [curScreen, setScreen] = useState("large-desktop");
  const getScreen = () => {
    let size = window.innerWidth;
    if (size < 600) return "mobile";
    else if (size < 1200) return "tablet";
    else if (size < 1800) return "desktop";
    else return "large-desktop";
  };

  //useEffect
  useEffect(() => {
    setScreen(() => getScreen());
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      ...
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: `setScreen(getScreen())` should work, arrow usage at `setState` made for initial values in most cases...

Answer (score 1):

With `() => getScreen()` you are passing the function definition as the value for `setScreen` only. Instead you need to call the function. Try as the following:

```
const [curScreen, setScreen] = useState("large-desktop");

useEffect(() => {
  const getScreen = () => {
      let size = window.innerWidth;
      if (size < 600) return "mobile";
      else if (size < 1200) return "tablet";
      else if (size < 1800) return "desktop";
      else return "large-desktop";
  };

  setScreen(getScreen());
}, []);
```

Or maybe try calling the function once you instantiate the `useState()`:

```
const [curScreen, setScreen] = useState(getScreen());
```

See the full code for the example:

```
function getScreen() {
    let size = window.innerWidth;
    if (size < 600) return "mobile";
    else if (size < 1200) return "tablet";
    else if (size < 1800) return "desktop";
    else return "large-desktop";
}

function App() {
  const [curScreen, setScreen] = useState(getScreen());

  return (
    <div className="App">
      ...
    </div>
  );
}
```

I hope this helps!